# Seeking Alabama GIS Clearinghouses?

Tags: data, united-states

Alabama's data portal (portal.gsa.state.al.us) is down and I haven't come across any other GIS clearinghouses for AL that are as good as say, Florida's FGDL.

Does anyone know of a decent GIS clearinghouse specific to Alabama?

Comment: lots of links but the go back to the Alabama portal unfortunately. How they resolve there web/ftp site issues.

Comment: @caitriggs - I've been here since 2007 and have not found any consolidation of data sources.  Just pointing that out to say that it's not just something you missed.  You might edit your question if there are specific data sets you are looking for.

Comment: I was able to find specifics by going to each agency directly. That's horribly time consuming though, especially since some had to dig up their data from the GIS department and then send directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIS Data for Alabama is available at the [Alabama GeoHub](http://data-algeohub.opendata.arcgis.com/), built using ArcGIS Hub, a platform for sharing open data.

Many open data sites have loose affiliations with state agencies, and may allow submissions by anyone who registers, including corporations and NGOs. It's not immediately clear who is responsible for the Alabama GeoHub, but the footer says "Copyright 2016. Alabama", and many of the submissions are by users whose usernames imply affiliation with a state or federal agency.

Answer (score -1):

Alabama doesn't really have an official GIS clearinghouse.  The state started a collection of data sets 1 or 2 years ago and has reported that they're working on improving data availability. Obviously that has yet to be seen with an exception of the new Geological Survey of Alabama (GSA) site.